# AttributeError: __enter__ while trying to take input from microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, attributeerror, microphone

I had been trying to take input from microphone in my python program using speech_recognition

I try to run this code: -

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
```

But it does not run.

It says: -

```
"C:\Users\Bravo Six\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "D:/BROTEEN/Works/Python/VALINI/speech testing.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/BROTEEN/Works/Python/VALINI/speech testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone as source:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Process finished with exit code 1

How can I solve this problem??? Please some help me get out of this situation!!!

```
I Ctrl + clicked on the sr.**Microphone**, wherein I saw that it said it throws an attribute error when pyaudio 0.2.11 or later is not installed. So I installed it using cmd, but the problem still sustains... HELP!!!
```

Comment: My guess would be to use `with sr.Microphone() as source`, at first glance it looks like you're just using the class and not a microphone objet

Comment: Didn't get it. How do I do that. I have followed many tutorials on youtube.!!! But still the problem sustains(btw i'm on windows 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same kind of problem happened to me, and I got it solved by coding it up like this:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
   #your code here
```

I hope this helps solve your problem. If you still are having some problems, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured that Windows 7 does not easily cooperate with the `speech_recognition` module... So I just switched to Windows 10 and now it works like buttery smooth! Thanks